# drag and drop an image-link into a textarea and extract source

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop, base64

I want to drag an image from another browser into a textarea of my website an then extract the image source. But var selected_file  is undefined.

html:

```
 <textarea id="input" type="file" rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>
```

js:

```
    document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('drop', function ( e ){

            e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var selected_file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    console.log(selected_file);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I proposed that you should download the image first into you local machine, and then drag the image into your website. Maybe this can help.